# transform array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, I have 2 arrays:

```
var state = {
  users: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Igor'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Anton'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Vasya'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Pete'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Dan'}
  ],

  chats: [
    {id: 1, users: [1,2], owner: 1},
    {id: 2, users: [1,2,3], owner: 2},
    {id: 3, users: [3,4,5], owner: 5}
  ]
}
```

I need a function that returns array like 'chats' but with actual names, not ids.
So far I got this:

```
function loadChats() {
  return state.chats.map(item =>
      ({
        id: item.id,
        users: item.users.map(user => 
          state.users.find(usr => 
            usr.id === user).name),
        owner: item.owner       
      })
    )
}
```

But I donk think that solution is good, because we dont need to map all the array, just 'users' in it. So can anybody suggest better solution?
I was thinking to do smth like this:

```
...  
state.chats.forEach(item =>
  item.users.map(user => 
    state.users.find(usr => 
      usr.id === user)
  )
)
...
```

But I don't like using forEach, is there any better solution?

Comment: Your state object in your example is wrong. `users` and `chats` should be assigned using `:` not `=`.

Comment: @AdamJeffers yeah I know, it was a typo. Fixed

Comment: @Tushar ids wont be numeral and in order, that is just example, they will be random 6-symbol combination

Comment: @ikffs Then you need an object having multiple elements inside it having key as `id`(unique` and value as username.

Comment: @Tushar yeah, I got it now

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off reducing the user array first and then directly referencing people by id, so you only loop over the users array once. It's no use to find the user in the array for every chat.

```
var users = state.users.reduce(function ( map, account ) {
        map[account.id] = account.name;
        return map;
    }, {}),
    conversations = state.chats.map(function ( chat ) {
        return {
            'id' : chat.id,
            'users' : chat.users.map(function ( id ) {
                return users[id];
            }),
            'owner' : users[chat.owner]
        };
    });
```

Comment: problem is that ids won't be numeral and in order, it was for example, they will be 6 random symbols

Comment: Doesn't matter, you're reducing the names into an object, and objects can have any valid string as a key.

Answer (score 0):

You're using arrow function so I guess you can use `[].find()`:

```js
var state = {
    users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Igor' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Anton' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Vasya' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Pete' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Dan' }
    ],

    chats: [
        { id: 1, users: [1, 2], owner: 1 },
        { id: 2, users: [1, 2, 3], owner: 2 },
        { id: 3, users: [3, 4, 5], owner: 5 }
    ]
};

var users = state.users;
var chats = state.chats;

chats = chats.map(function each(chat) {
    // this replace the chat.users array and doesn't touch or hard code any other property
    chat.users = chat.users.map(function (id) {
        return users.find(function (user) {
            return user.id == id;
        }).name;
    });

    return chat;
});

console.log(chats);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(chats, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```